# Parametrizing node name in Elixir Exrm

Tags: elixir, exrm

I want to use Exrm with Erlang distributed on a single machine.

I need to create multiple releases that differ only with node name.

I know, I can configure node name in `rel/vm.args`, but it will be static. Can I somehow generate multiple releases with different node name?

Comment: At the risk of making a dumb suggestion--why not just hack together a bash script to do what you want?  Copy the rel/vm.args and modify the node name string in each copy.

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. I was just curious, if there is a more standard way to do it.

Comment: @bitwalker would be the one to answer this.  Maybe post a link to your question on the Elixir mailing list so he can see your question.

Comment: When starting the release, can't you still pass arguments through the command line? If you can, you can just pass them in `bin/erl -name ...` overriding the ones in vm.args?

Answer (score 4):

I am researching the same issue. A possible approach:

The `rel/vm.args` supports OS environment variables parametrization. So you can do something like

```
## Name of the node
-name ${MY_NODE_NAME}

## Cookie for distributed erlang
-setcookie ${MY_COOKIE}
```

Then you would invoke in batch file:

```
export RELX_REPLACE_OS_VARS=true
export MY_NODE_NAME=foobar@my_host
export MY_COOKIE=foobar
```

Note `RELX_REPLACE_OS_VARS` -- it is important!