# EXRM - Can I set vm.args values from the config.exs file?

Tags: config, elixir, elixir-mix, beam, exrm

Somewhat related to this question - [Parametrizing node name in Elixir Exrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406725/parametrizing-node-name-in-elixir-exrm) - is there a way to dynamically set the content of the rel/vm.args file?

In the title, I suggest the use of config.exs, but I'm interested in any scheme that will allow me to add, remove and edit vm arguments at build time.

A bash script might be an idea, but a solution that would also work on Windows, and is preferably based on Elixir code would be the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can commit to your project repo a `rel/vm.args` file that you would like to be used instead of the *Exrm* generated one.  *Exrm* will automatically use this file instead.